# google places api fetch more than 60 results

Tags: php, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm currently working with google places api to fetch nightclubs in the given city, 
I have evn added my credit card to API details as per you documentation I was supposed to get 150K hits per day.
when I hit the google places api it returns only 60 places in 3 pages.
Please assits how can I can more results from API query.

Comment: because that's the number of nightclubs in a given city

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to get more than 60 results from places search request. This behavior is well documented.

> By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging

Adding more results might open a possibility for data scraping that is prohibited by Terms of Service [1], so it is very unlikely that Google increases the number of items in the response.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4

> **No creation or augmentation of data sets based on Google’s Content or Services.** You will not use Google’s Content or Services to create or augment your own mapping-related dataset (or that of a third party), including a mapping or navigation dataset, business listings database, mailing list, or telemarketing list.