# Google Place API

Tags: google-maps, web, google-places-api

How do I retrive more that 60 result from google place API with NearBy Search or Text Search? There is any way to get unlimited records. (paid or free).

Comment: I used this query to get nearby results: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=18.563214,73.777192&radius=10000&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyALWvJHwW8SfYKGSKpEZd00uLzhcYKMu4g

Comment: But for getting next result i used next_page_token but i am able to get mazimum upto 60 results only. I want to get more results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google places api fetch more than 60 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106501/google-places-api-fetch-more-than-60-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get more than 60 results in Places API. Some people tried to file a feature request in Google issue tracker, but Google rejected it with the following comment

> Unfortunately Places API is not in a position to return more than 60 results.
>
> Besides technical reasons (latency, among others) returning more than 60 results would make the API be more like a database or general-purpose search engine. We'd rather improve search quality so that users don't need to go so far down a long list of results.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826799